# How to maintain atomicity with a service like pattern

Tags: design-patterns, mvc

Imagine a route in an MVC web project which handles editing a user of your product. You can do things like change their name, their email, their group, their roles and so forth.
This data is put in a form and sent to the server.

Now imagine that we have a UserManager service to handle these actions. How do I make sure my route is atomic when the process could fail after an arbitrary number of actions?

```
userManager.SetEmail(userID, newEmail) // passes, no duplicate emails, email ok.
userManager.SetPassword(userID, newPassword) // passes, password validates.
userManager.SetGroup(userID, newGroupID) // FAIL!!! group id is invalid or something.
```

The functions above would alter the email and password before failing on the group setting.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: Why is that something you want to avoid?

Comment: @Telastyn I think that a form on a website should be atomic. If the form is redisplayed with big red validation errors then I think the user will assume that the request was not fulfilled.

Comment: then why would your service treat each of the parts as a distinct operation?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [memento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).

At each step you look at the previous state and store it in a temporary object. If at any time there is a failure that requires rolling back, you simply look at each memento and restore the original state. This should normally be done as a [LIFO stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) to ensure changes are undone in reverse order.

Note the term "roll back" here: at a high level, this is exactly how [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) transactions work in modern relational databases. It is the same idea in a database as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If the "userManager" exposes separate methods for setting the email, the password, etc. then it is explicitly exposing a model in which partial failure is possible and to be expected.

Sure, you can roll your own rollback mechanism as Snowman suggested, but I think it would be easier (more pragmatic perhaps?) to just add the ability to your "userManager" to accept an entire group of properties to be modified at once, (atomically,) so that it is the userManager's responsibility to make sure that all operations will succeed before applying them, or to make use of whatever transactioning mechanism might be made available to it by the underlying rdbms, the existence of which it is trying to abstract.